# Is there a way to change the workset configuration of a revit file without opening revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am currently trying to close all worksets of a revit model before opening it programmatically using C#. Without a valid API instance I am lost on how to close worksets prior to opening. I have seen other software such as Revit Batch Processor accomplish this: https://github.com/bvn-architecture/RevitBatchProcessor . But after going through their source code, I still can't seem to figure it out.

I have tried opening the file.manually and simulating input to accomplish this, but I want to know if there is a way to do it properly.

EDIT: This is for a local file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for pointing out the very useful- and full-fledged-looking batch processor. I would be surprised if you could close worksets of a Revit model before opening it. What makes you think that the batch processor does so? I searched for `OpenDocumentFile` and found it in `revit_file_util.py` with nothing special in it for handling worksets.

Comment: First off, Thank you for everything you do Jeremy. You are an incredible help with everything to do with the Revit API. When using OpenDocumentFile, is there a way to close worksets after opening the file?

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation! Apparently, you can close the worksets during the document open, according to the answer to [Open/Close Worksets in current document](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/open-close-worksets-in-current-document/td-p/10435771): Check the Remarks section of the API docs on the [WorksetConfiguration](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/eefef6f4-0892-4bb5-8840-5e99aebc65c9.htm).

Comment: I just found this by searching myself for [revit api close workset](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=revit+api+close+workset). Try it out; you can search and find things yourself as well  :-)